# What difference between errors.Wrap and errors.WithMessage

Tags: go

github.com/pkg/errors

This is `Wrap(err error, msg string)` https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pkg/errors#Wrap

This is `WithMessage(err error, msg string)` https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pkg/errors#WithMessage

both of these functions implement the interface `causer` https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/pkg/errors#Cause

This code works with `errors.WithMessage`, although I thought I should use `errors.Wrap` for `errors.Cause`

```
func main() {
    err := errors.New("first")
    err1 := errors.WithMessage(err, "tmp")
    err2 := errors.WithMessage(err1, "tmp")
    err3 := errors.WithMessage(err2, "tmp")
    fmt.Printf("%s", errors.Cause(err3))
}
```

`Output: first`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that `Wrap` includes a call stack. If you click on a function name in the Go documentation, it will take you to the source, and you can see that both these functions are quite short and simple, and there is only one difference; while `WithMessage` creates a new error with the given message and cause (the error you pass in), `Wrap` takes this error and wraps it *again* like so:

```
&withStack{
    err,
    callers(),
}
```

Here `err` is the new error it just created (exactly like what you'd get from `WithMessage`) and `callers` populates a call stack. This is indicated in the documentation (emphasis mine):

> Wrap returns an error **annotating err with a stack trace** at the point Wrap is called

Which is not mentioned in `WithMessage` as it's not done by that function.